# my app is working fine but i have many errors in log so how can i fix this error : Bad activity token: android.os.BinderProxy@ca1c911

Tags: android, token

Bad activity token: android.os.BinderProxy@ca1c911

```
10-30 10:29:58.224 688-2409/? W/ActivityManager: Bad activity token: android.os.BinderProxy@c676ce2
                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.forTokenLocked(ActivityRecord.java:757)
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.isInStackLocked(ActivityRecord.java:1753)
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.getStackLocked(ActivityRecord.java:1758)
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getActivityStackId(ActivityManagerService.java:13260)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:3045)
                                                     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3698)
                                                     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be general error from system or any other apps. Check you are looking into your application specific logs.
[image]

Make sure you have selected your application package in second dropdown and in the last dropdown you need to select `Show only selected application` option only than logcat will display application specific logs, otherwise it will show all the logs.